# Accordion expand card with react and css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to make this card in such a way that when you click on view details, the card's blue footer should expand in height and shows the lorem text, and then clicking on another card the previous card will get collapsed. The issue is when I click on `view details` the card's blue bottom is not expanding with the lorem. Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bohr-by01z?file=/src/App.js

App.js:

```
import { Card, Footer, Header } from "./styles";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Header>last viewed: {null}</Header>
        <Footer>
          <span onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>View Details</span>
          {expanded && (
            <div className="accodion">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos,
              facilis. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Eos, facilis. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
              elit. Eos, facilis. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
              adipisicing elit. Eos, facilis.
            </div>
          )}
        </Footer>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

styles.js:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Card = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ isEmpty }) => (isEmpty ? "#FAFAFA" : "white")};
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 8px;
`;

const DropDown = styled.div`
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Header = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: -40;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #7894b0;
  margin: 16px;
`;
const Footer = styled.div`
  background-color: rgb(242, 247, 251);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;

  .accodion {
    padding: 30px;
  }
`;

export { Card, Header, Footer, DropDown };
```

Comment: Try setting `min-height: 50px;` instead of `height: 50px` to the footer. Right now is a fixed height so it won't grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution need additional switch class *.show* and get the *height* for the current footer with *useRef*. Also adding second *useState* where will keep the whole *footer height*. [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fast-eid3m?file=/src/App.js)

**Styled-components**

```
const Card = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ isEmpty }) => (isEmpty ? '#FAFAFA' : 'white')};
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 8px;
`;

const DropDown = styled.div`
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Header = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: -40;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #7894b0;
  margin: 16px;
`;
const Footer = styled.div`
  background-color: rgb(242, 247, 251);
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px; /* changed */
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; /* added */
  overflow: hidden; /* added */

  span {
    padding: 12px 0;
  }

  .accodion {
    padding: 10px 15px 15px; /* changed */
  }

  &.show {
    height: ${({ setHeight }) => setHeight}px;
  }
`;
```

**App.js**

```
import { Card, Footer, Header } from "./styles";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [accodionHeight, setAccodionHeight] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const open = () => setExpanded(!expanded);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getHeight = ref.current.scrollHeight;
    setAccodionHeight(getHeight);
  }, [expanded]);

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Header>last viewed: {null}</Header>
        <Footer
          onClick={open}
          className={expanded ? "show" : ""}
          setHeight={accodionHeight}
          ref={ref}
        >
          <span>View Details</span>
          <div className="accodion" ref={ref}>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos,
            facilis. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Eos, facilis. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Eos, facilis. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Eos, facilis.
          </div>
        </Footer>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```